# How to convert a Date in a dynamically added input field (JSF)

Tags: date, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, converters, html-input

In my application I want to enter a date in an `<input>` field which is programatically created for a JSF page.

The creation of the input field looks like this:

```
// Input
String jsfValue = String.format("#{%s.item.%s}", getELClassname(), property.getKey());
ValueExpression valueExpression = JSFUtils.createValueExpression(jsfValue, property.getValue());

HtmlInputText input = (HtmlInputText) app.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
input.setId(property.getKey());
input.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);
```

The `property` is an instance of `java.util.Date` and the `<input>` field is just an `HtmlInputText` component without any converter assigned to it.

When the `<input>` tag is rendered, then the following value can be seen for a date:

```
Tue Mar 11 18:31:20 CET 2014
```

If I know want to save the form, then the JSF page complains about the format of the date because it is not able to convert the input value to a `java.util.Date`.

Can someone tell me how I can create a converter programatically for a `HtmlInputText` component?

When I was using `MyFaces` for my application then the conversion was done automatically because I never had this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeConverter converter = (DateTimeConverter) application.createConverter(Date.class);
converter.setPattern(somePattern);
input.setConverter(converter);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But instead of createConverter(Date.class) one should use createConverter("javax.faces.DateTime").

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to apply a `DateTimeConverter` to the dynamically created input field so that JSF knows how to convert the given String into a proper `java.util.Date`.

Here is a code sample:

```
HtmlInputText input = (HtmlInputText) app.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
...
DateTimeConverter converter = (DateTimeConverter) app.createConverter(DateTimeConverter.CONVERTER_ID);
converter.setPattern("mm/dd/yyyy");
input.setConverter(converter);
```

If other date formats are needed, you can take a look at Wikipedia: [Date format by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).